# d3.js passing bound function does not appear to execute the function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript

I am trying to reuse some code that makes x-axis ticks. Here is the method I've put it in:

```
xTicks: (scale, dayTickFormat) ->
    d3.svg.axis().scale(scale).orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickSize(10)
    .tickFormat(dayTickFormat)
    .tickPadding(8)
```

Please pardon the coffeescript :\

Anyway, I here is the code that calls that:

```
drawTicks: (chart, chartOptions, margin, x, y, num_y_ticks) ->

    xTickGroup = chart.append("g").attr("class", "day-ticks")
    .call(@xTicks.bind(@, x, dayTickFormat))
    .attr("transform", "translate(#{chartOptions.offset.left}, #{chartOptions.height - 10})")
```

When this code executes, I don't get any ticks. I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suspect it's because the way I am returning that "d3.svg.axis()..." but I am not sure I understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, nvm, I got it.

call() wasn't calling the "d3.svg.axis()" bit, it was calling the method I had wrapped around it. So, if I store my method in a variable like so:

```
xTicks = @xTicks(x, dayTickFormat)
```

I can call it more simply like this:

```
xTickGroup = chart.append("g").attr("class", "day-ticks")
.call(xTicks)
.attr("transform", "translate(#{chartOptions.offset.left}, #{chartOptions.height - 10})")
```

Hope this helps someone, someday :\